Installing Headers on Kali 6.1.0-kali5-arm64
I have a TP-Linh Archer T2U Nano (Realtek RTL8811AU) and I want to use it with the Kernel 6.1.0-kali5-arm64.
I already installed the drivers for the newest Kernels and it works fine, but for this one I'm not able to do it because I need to install the headers for the Kernel 6.1.0-kali5-arm64 but they can't be found.
I received the following error message:
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 6.1.0-kali5-arm64 cannot be found at /lib/modules/6.1.0-kali5-arm64/build or /lib/modules/6.1.0-kali5-arm64/source.
Please install the linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-arm64 package or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located.

Running sudo apt install linux-headers-6.1.0-kalki5-arm64 returns
Error: Unable to locate package linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-arm64
Error: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-6.1.0-kali5-arm64'

How can I find and install the headers for this Kernel's version?
Using VMware Fusion 13.6.1

I was able to find the headers here:
https://old.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/
